# Mac OS X frozen with Apache

Tags: macos, apache, lamp, macos-high-sierra

I setup PHP and MySQL with brew for my Macbook pro on MacOS 10.13.4 High Sierra. When I run any apache command my whole system freeze,apps are not responding (impossible to open or close them, I have to turn off my computer by hand) :

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

or

```
sudo apachectl  stop
```

If I run -e debug at the same time, no errors appear and it finishes the process.

Your help would be very appreciated since I am developer and I can't work without apache :)

Thanks,
T

Comment: The solution was to remove all old brew dependencies (i used rmtree) from an old version of httpd and reinstall with brew the new version of httpd. https://github.com/beeftornado/homebrew-rmtree

Comment: Much obliged, you saved my macbook from getting thrown out the window -- it was close!

Comment: What was those old brew dependencies? I removed httpd with rmtree, installed again, and the issue still persists.